# Can I use "if else statement" inside row.add()?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Can I use if else statement inside row.add()?

My html code:

```
<table id="myTableSub">
<thead>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="insert" id="insert" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="select"  id="select"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="update" id="update"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="delete"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>...</tfoot>
</table>
```

My js:

```
var tableSub = $('#myTableSub').DataTable();
...
if (data) {
$.each(data, function (i, tdData) {
var insert = tdData['INSERT'];
tableSub.row.add(
if (insert == 1)
document.getElementById("insert").checked = true,
tdData['SELECT'],
tdData['UPDATE'],
tdData['DELETE']]).draw().node();
});
} else {
....
}
```

I want if insert is equal to 1, checkbox will be checked.

Comment: `row.add` is a method, so it accepts expressions. Using statements is invalid syntax. Why would you even want to have the `if`` *inside* the invocation instead of outside?

Comment: No. And you cannot have duplicate IDs

Comment: I see. Thank you guys :3